# How do I handle the UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning in Node.JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, try-catch

I have a few methods that use the `request` module to get images from URLs and returns it as a Promise, it works but when the image isn't found it rejects the promise with the status code 404. I looked into that warning and it is said that to handle the rejection you have to setup a catch callback after then() but I don't use then(), I use async/await.

This is the code to get the picture:

```js
/**
 * Returns picture from S3
 * @param {String} filename Name of the file with extension
 * @returns {String} Base64 string of the file
 */
getPictureFromS3: function (filename) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        let url = this.getURLFromS3(filename);
        request(url, (err, res, body) => {
            if (err) reject(err);
            if (res.statusCode !== 200) {
                reject(`Invalid status code <${res.statusCode}>`);
            }
            resolve(new Buffer.from(body).toString('base64'));
        });
    });
}
```

And this is how I call the method:

```js
try{
    socket.on('server get pictures', () => db.getPictures(data=>{
        if(data!==null){
            data.forEach(async e=>{
                let picture = await utils.getPictureFromS3(e.getFilename());
            });
        }
    }));
}catch(err){
    console.log(err);
}
```

Full warning:

```
(node:256) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Invalid status code <404>
(node:256) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which 
was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:256) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Using Node v10.14.2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two problems here

- You care trying to do async operation inside `forEach` which doesn't work with promises. You need to use `for..of` loop or `Promise.all` if you can do things in parallel.
- The exception is raise inside the listener so it will not bubble up outside so your catch wouldn't be executed. You need to move your try catch inside. Something like this

```
socket.on("server get pictures", () =>
  db.getPictures(data => {
    if (data !== null) {
      for(const e of data) {
        try {
          let picture = await utils.getPictureFromS3(e.getFilename());
        } catch (err) {
          console.log(err);
        }
      }
    }
  })
);
```

Comment: Perfect it logs the error correctly now thanks! But I had to put async in db.getPictures(async data otherwise it wouldn't.